# how to get values from 2 component UIPickerView? swift

Tags: swift

I have a UIPickerView set up with two components, using a 2d array, so how do I get each currently selected value?

(ex: users can pick a color and a shape in a 2 segments picker, how would i get the currently selected color and shape?)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UIPickerView` method `selectedRowInComponent:`

Ask it for the selected value of component 0, then for component 1.